# vs-code: syntax-highlighting of typescript in html

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for a way to mix html and typescript in the same file and still have syntax/error-highlighting like in a normal "ts" file?

I found that I can change the type of a script-tag to "text/typescript" and retain some of the highlighting but not all. With the command `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` it says language `html` inside this script-tag:

[image]
Maybe just the type of language can be changed for this tag with some configuration?
Maybe there is some other way?

Comment: For me syntax highlighting like in your sample works out of the box. Maybe any extension breaks this behaviour? You could try ```code --disable-extensions``` to run an instance without extensions. And also please note that browsers do not understand typescript - you will need to transpile it to JS.

Comment: Well ... the syntax-highlighting is not the only issue. The most important stuff is the underlining of errors and unknown variables. That does not work in these tags. I don't have any extensions installed.

Comment: I want to do this for developing web-components where I put the typescript code and the template definition (for the shadow-dom) in a separate file. The build-process will "compile" everything into the final *.html so no typescript will hit the browser --> but it is still nicer to have just a single file for the component instead of separating the code and the template.

Comment: Some time ago script type module (for ES modules) has been added to the standard and vs-code detects this type correctly and formats everything in it as javascript. If you use an unknown type for the script-tag the language used inside is just plain html. So i was thinking that it can't be that hard to just change the language used for a typescript-tag --> that it can be configured somewhere ... but I haven't found anything.

Comment: I wish there would be a solution for this